# How to download and automatic install apk from url in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, apk, inputstream

I'm trying to programmatically download an `.apk` file from a given URL and then install it, but I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`. What could be a possible reason for the issue?

```
        try {
                URL url = new URL(fileURL);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();

                String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Download/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "VersionUpdate.apk");
                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

**//Getting error in this line** 

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();



                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                is.close();




            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
}

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            //dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/download/VersionUpdate.apk"),"application/vnd.android.package-archive"); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Google won't like what you are trying to do.

Comment: please provide the logcat error

Comment: Swapna, FileNotFound means that file is misplaced on some other location I think, whatever file you are looking is not at that place.

Answer (score 2):

You just replaced by **InputStream is = c.getInputStream();** to given code.

```
InputStream is ;
    int status = c.getResponseCode();
    if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
       is = c.getErrorStream();
    else
       is = c.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
 File outputFile = new File(file, "VersionUpdate.apk");
 if(!outputFile.exists())
 {

   outputFile.createNewFile();
 }
```

What you are doing is deleting the file, when it already exist, then `FileOutputStream` will not get file where you want to download the `apk` .

If the file already exist, `FileOutputStream` will override the content with new update.

If you have queries, do ask!!